# How can I remove a user category from a template?

Tags: resharper, resharper-6.0, resharper-7.0

How can I remove a user category from a Resharper Live Template? When only a category is selected (and not a template itself) the delete button is disabled:

[image: Resharper Live Templates]

None of the items provide context menus, and editing a template does not provide any way to edit it's categories.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From the [JetBrains issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-287973):

> There is a way.
>
> You just select that category, and drag the template
>   out to the "All" category.

(and I feel I must also quote a user comment:

> Your solution works but is not intuitive at all.

Quite.)

Comment: As a side note, (at least in R# v10) this seems to only work if you drag one at a time...